# Does Access token retrieve user alias

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have an access token to access WEBAPI from UI.

I am able to get user alias using below properties:

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name
```

I am not getting how come access token providing user alias using above properties.

Can someone clarify on this.

Comment: What is your @Chandra Sekhar ? is it a Web App?

Comment: Yes.It is web app

Answer (score 0):

JWTs are split into three piece:

**Header** - Provides information about how to validate the token including information about the type of token and how it was signed.
**Payload** - **Contains all of the important data about the user or app** that is attempting to call your service.
**Signature** - Is the raw material used to validate the token.

The `oid` **uniquely identifies the user across applications**. Thus, `oid` can be used when making queries to Microsoft online services, such as the Microsoft Graph. The Microsoft Graph will return this ID as the id property for a given user account.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens).